# If $p\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ evaluate :

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, congruences

$S=$ #$\{x\in \mathbb{F}_p^{*} \ / \ x^{\frac{p-2}{3}}=1 \}$ ?

Let consider $\phi : \mathbb{F}_p^* \to \mathbb{F}_p^*, \ x \mapsto x^{\frac{p-2}{3}}$ a homomorphism. By property we will have : #$\ker(\phi)$$=$#$S$.

But how to determine #$\ker(\phi)$ ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: By Fermat's little theorem $x^{p-1} = 1$. Also if $x^{(p-2)/3}=1$ then $x^{\frac{p-2}{3}\times3}=x^{p-2} = 1$. So......

Comment: Can you show that $\phi$ is an epimorphism (i.e., $\phi$ is surjective)? Then, you can conclude that $\ker\phi$ is trivial using the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Slightly more generally (I'm sure the other commenters also had this in mind): In a cyclic group of order $n$ the $k$th powers form a subgroup of order $n/\gcd(n,k)$.

Comment: @HwChu so finally $x=1$ !

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know this statement but do you have a proof ? Maybe with $Z/nZ$ ?